# How to make Finder remember the column width of List View?

Tags: macos, finder, macos-catalina

I always use List View in Finder. When I open a new Finder window, the "Name" column is too narrow to see the full file name. (Like the screenshot below.)

[Sometimes Finder column width of List View is so narrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXnLL.png)

**So, is there any way to make Finder remember the column width of List View, or change the default column width?**

I did some search, and there's one solution said "press option key at the same time of changing column width" ... but that's work for "Column View", instead of column of "List View". So, please don't repeat that solution.

My operating system is macOS Catalina 10.15.2 ... It's said to that this issue is a Catalina bug, is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

In List View, the only way I got it to remain wide was to uncheck most of the column settings (i.e. remove Date Added, Date Last Opened, etc.).  To get there, right click on the top row where it says, "Name, Date Modified, Size, etc.".